# How to control fluentd log tag from Docker

Tags: logging, docker, fluentd

Current setup is running Docker containers with the `fluentd` driver:

```
docker run --log-driver=fluentd my-container
```

That works quite easily...sends stdout to the locally running fluentd system on the host.

I'd like to control the fluentd `tag` using some of the labels which are set on the container.  For this example, assume some labels (`docker inspect` snippet):

```
"Config": {
    "Labels": {
       "com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name": "web",
       "com.amazonaws.ecs.task-definition-version": "3"
    }
}
```

How can I set the `fluentd` `tag` by extracting out one or more of the `Labels`?

The Docker docs on this list out the currently supported tags: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/log_tags/

Those docs make note of `ExtraAttributes`...however I can figure out how to use that to look up one or more labels.  Reading through the Docker code it's not clear to me: https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/daemon/logger/context.go#L29

This is trivial to do with `docker inspect`:

```
docker inspect --format '{{index .ContainerLabels "com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name"}}'
```

I'd like to grep out the same information and get it into `log-opt tag=?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ContainerLabels` map is one of the [items available in dockers logging Context](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/6401bd65b11931a27a6d2e1d3b6a9278ed4e8fc7/daemon/logger/context.go#L10-L24) and the [fluentd driver supports ParseLogTag](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/6401bd65b11931a27a6d2e1d3b6a9278ed4e8fc7/daemon/logger/fluentd/fluentd.go#L68) so you can use go template formatting.

In straight docker this would look like:

```
docker run \
  --label alabel=1value \
  --log-driver=fluentd \
  --log-opt tag="{{ .ContainerLabels.alabel }}" \
  busybox \
  echo "$(date) test log"
```

So if you can inject a `--log-opt` into your ECS startup as follows:

```
--log-opt tag='{{ index .ContainerLabels "com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name" }}'
```

You should get your tag.

`index` is required here to [access map keys with non alpha numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267608/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-key-containing-dots)

Comment: Beautiful...this is exactly what I needed. Thanks @Matt!

Comment: Any ideas why the following: `tag: '{{ index .ContainerLabels "io.rancher.stack.name" }}'` gives me a yaml error: > found unexpected end of stream? (working on `rancher 1.6.10`)

Comment: That sounds like a JSON character is not being escaped in the TAG?