# Is there a way to make the Docker Splunk Driver send the EC2 Instance Id to Splunk when it runs on the AWS EC2 Container Service (ECS)?

Tags: docker, splunk, amazon-ecs

My Docker containers are managed by ECS (EC2 Container Service) on AWS.
The ECS cluster decides on which EC2 instance a container is going to run.

I see that there is a way to configure the Splunk driver to send the Docker container Id and/or the container name to Splunk with each log entry, but I can't find a way to send the EC2 instance Id. There doesn't seem to be a variable for this (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/log_tags).

Comment: Is the EC2 instance ID available when you run `docker inspect` on the container?

Answer (score 0):

This [similar question for fluentd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38799403/1318694) covers the detail of setting a tag via log options.

On ECS you can add your custom "Log options" to the "Log Configuration" of the task or service:

key = `tag`
value = `{{ index .ContainerLabels "com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name" }}`

#### Instance ID

It doesn't look like ECS sends the EC2 instance ID to Docker and [it's really hard in ECS to populate anything from the hosts environment](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/3).

The hostname is available in Docker as a `--log-opt tag` via `{{ .Hostname }}` so it might be easiest to set your hostname to the instance ID and use that.

The instance ID is available via http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id

You could use a user-data script to set the hostname at build time or startup script to set the hostname every time an instance boots.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -ue

INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id)

# Set the network hostname
sed -ri "s/^HOSTNAME=.*/HOSTNAME=$INSTANCE_ID/" /etc/sysconfig/network

# Set the local host lookup
if ! grep -Eq "127.0.0.1.*$INSTANCE_ID" /etc/hosts; then 
  sed -ri "s/^(127.0.0.1.*)/\1 $INSTANCE_ID/" /etc/hosts
fi
```

I think you could do something similar if you run a [local splunk forwarder](https://github.com/outcoldman/docker-splunk) on each EC2 instance and add tags or fields there.